# ExcelDNA C# Chart.MouseDown event firing only once

Tags: c#, excel, event-handling, excel-dna

i'm tryng to have an handle the event every time I click on a chart, on each worksheet of an opened workbook.
I'm using the SheetActivate event like this:

```
private static void Xlapp_SheetActivate(Object obj_Ws)
    {
        myCharts.SetAllCharts((XL.Worksheet)obj_Ws);
    }
```

to call a method every time a worksheet is activated, and then the "SetAllCharts" method in the "MyCharts" class that looks like:

```
internal void SetAllCharts(object obj_Ws)
    {
        XL.Worksheet Ws = (XL.Worksheet)obj_Ws;
        XL.ChartObjects ChObj = Ws.ChartObjects();

        if (ChObj.Count > 0)
        {
            xlapp.StatusBar = ("Setting " + ChObj.Count + " charts");
            foreach (XL.ChartObject obj_Chart in ChObj)
            {
                XL.Chart myChart = obj_Chart.Chart;
                myChart.MouseDown += myChart_MouseDown;
            }
        }
    }
```

for now, the method handler (simply a `xlapp.StatusBar` message that reports X and Y of the click) works... only once, the first time I activate a worksheet, on the first click on a chart. After that i'm not getting the message box anymore...
What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with the lifetime of the COM objects (or at least the magic .NET wrappers around them) that you set event handlers on. They might be created on the fly as you enumerate a collection and garbage collected soon after, losing your event handler in the process. That's why it works once or a few times.

The test for this, before you start thinking about how to write the code, is to keep the objects in some higher object level or global list.
In your code this would be the `obj_Chart` object you are enumerating. Just make sure these objects are all kept alive.

(I find this stuff a bit confusing because the opposite happen with WPF - I think the event handlers prevent things from garbage collecting?)